# Repeat each row of a matrix

Tags: matlab

I have variable `A` of size `m` by `n`. I want to generate `B` of size `m` by `m*n`, such as below example.
Example:

```
A = [1 2 3;
     4 5 6;
     7 8 9]
```

Should result with

```
B = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9;
     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9;
     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

Is there any way to do that without using loop? `m` and `n` is variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Repmat is indeed the way to go here, as mentioned by @Nerea. This solution should give the same answer as his, but personally I consider it to be a bit more elegant:

```
B=repmat(reshape(A',1,[]),size(A,1),1);
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use the `repmat` Matlab funtion:

`B = repmat(A,M,N)` creates a large matrix B consisting of an `M`-by-`N`
    tiling of copies of `A`. The size of `B` is `[size(A,1)*M, size(A,2)*N]`.
    The statement  `repmat(A,N)` creates an `N`-by-`N` tiling.

For your specific case one solution may be:

```
A=A';
B=repmat(A(:)',3,1);
```

And for the general case one solution may be:

```
A_aux=reshape(A',1,size(A,1)*size(A,2));
B=repmat(A_aux,size(A,1),1);
```

Comment: Repmat seems to be right, but transposing and shaping the matrix like a vector seems undesirable. Consider the case where `A = rand(2)` and think on what the output should be.

Comment: I have shaped the matrix like a vector because I think that @Meher81 wants the matrix B containing matrix A expanded like a vector in each of its rows.

Comment: I indeed misinterpreted the question, however I think there was a small bug in your solution as well (output would only be 1 column), so I took the liberty of updating this answer and merging in some elements of my own. --- I am not sure whether you cancelled my edit on purpose, but make sure to check it out.

Comment: Thank you for your comments @Dennis. I think I have solve the 1 column output problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

To include a quite fast [**`bsxfun`**](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/08/04/comparing-repmat-and-bsxfun-performance/) solution:

```
A = [1  2  3  4;
     5  6  7  8;
     9 10 11 12]

A = A.' %'
B = bsxfun(@plus,zeros(size(A,2),1),A(:).')
```

or use [**`kron`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html), but its surely slower:

```
A = A.'
B = kron(A(:),ones(1,size(A,2))).'
```

---

```
B =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12
```

Comment: `bsxfun` is so much FUN!

Comment: You're getting the hang of `bsxfun`! :-)

Answer (score 3):

No `repmat`s

```
[m n] = size(A);
B = ones(m,1) * reshape( A.', 1, [] );
```

Answer (score 0):

**One approach** 
with [`repmat`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html?refresh=true), [`reshape`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) and [`permute`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) combo!

```
out = repmat(reshape(permute(A,[3 2 1]),1,[]),size(A,1),1,1);
```

or **Another approach** without `reshape` but becomes a 2 liner

```
out1 = permute(A,[3 2 1]);
out = repmat(out1(:).',size(A,1),1,1);
```